# Is large Muslim immigration within an European country a cause for higher sexual violence in that particular country?

Tags: immigration, europe, violence

An [article](https://www.frontpagemag.com/fpm/271213/most-dangerous-countries-europe-women-have-large-daniel-greenfield) in [FrontPage Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontPage_Magazine) argues that:

> the more open a European country is to Muslim mass migration, the more
>   dangerous it is to women.

It provides various examples of European countries that accept quite many immigrants over the time and links this to higher sexual violence events number.

However, overall the article seems quite biased and provides no references to large studies, so I am interested in if there is at least one fairly large study that supports the assumption of the article.

**Question:** Is large Muslim immigration within an European country a cause for higher sexual violence in that particular country?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [Is Sweden experiencing a "rape epidemic"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31153) -- [Are crime rates up by 10% in Germany?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41524) -- [Is the immigrant / crime correlation simply explained by lower wealth?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15948). That's just the first page of my first search's results. Plus the caveat, if I remember correctly, some European countries have recently changed the definition of sexual violence under the law, which might skew related statistics.

Comment: @DevSolar - yes, they are clearly related, but since they are quite old questions at single country level. I am interested to have some study at EU level.

Comment: @Alexi: And you think you will find a common denominator that will cover the situation in Greece and Italy, as well as Germany and France, as well as Hungary, Estonia and Portugal?

Comment: @DevSolar - not sure about this. Immigration is an EU wide issue for some time, maybe I am lucky.

Comment: That article is blatant cherry picking. **They first state there is a relation**, then pick **some** numbers from **some** countries to 'prove' that.